# Twitter Api - how to verify if someone follow me

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, api, twitter

I'm so noob in Twitter Api and I need help! So what I have now? I've created a form where members of my website can follow somebody by clicking on follow buttons from twitter. Okay the part with following is done but how can I check in that form if the member following me or not when he's clicking on 'Claim Free Copy' button to get a error if he's not following? ..I think this is so hard to make but I hope you can help me because there on stackoverflow are the best developers. So the form looks like this

Comment: Sorry, SO isn't a coding service.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please check [this](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/friendships/show) article!

You can invoke the `API` like the example below - 

`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/show.json?source_screen_name=bert&target_screen_name=ernie`

You can then parse the `JSON` response to fulfill your requirement.

[image]